# Error on Partition over row number

Tags: oracle

I am creating a sub-query to select distinct entries on a certain column, DIS_COL, then return all other columns for those distinct entries, arbitrarily selecting the first row.

To do this I'm creating a sub-query that selects only first rows using over - partition by, then selecting from that sub-query.

There is an error with my code however; "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected".

My code is below:

```
select *
from (
   select *,
          row_number() over (partition by DIS_COL order by COL_2) as row_number --ORDER BY FIELD DETERMINES WHICH ROW IS THE FIRST ROW AND THUS WHICH ONE IS SELECTED.
   from MY_TABLE
   ) as rows
where row_number = 1
AND CRITERIA_COL = 'CRIT_1'
OR CRITERIA_COL_2 = 'CRIT_2';
```

How can I correct my code to achieve the desired result?

I am working on an Oracle database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `as rows`. It is not proper syntax for the table/query alias. It is syntax for column alias.

```
select *
from (
   select T.*, 
          row_number() over (partition by DIS_COL order by COL_2) as row_number --ORDER BY FIELD DETERMINES WHICH ROW IS THE FIRST ROW AND THUS WHICH ONE IS SELECTED.
   from MY_TABLE t
   ) 
where row_number = 1
AND (CRITERIA_COL = 'CRIT_1'
OR CRITERIA_COL_2 = 'CRIT_2');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the ROW_NUMBER, it's the `*,`  Add an alias to the subquery:

```
select *
from (
   select T.*, -- here
          row_number() over (partition by DIS_COL order by COL_2) as row_number --ORDER BY FIELD DETERMINES WHICH ROW IS THE FIRST ROW AND THUS WHICH ONE IS SELECTED.
   from MY_TABLE
   )T as rows -- and here
where row_number = 1
AND CRITERIA_COL = 'CRIT_1'
OR CRITERIA_COL_2 = 'CRIT_2';
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Unfortunately I'm now getting a "sql command not properly ended" error on the "as" in "as rows". Not sure why. I've tried explicilitly naming all columns in the subquery (e.g. T. DIS_COL) but that's not working. Do you know what it is that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what is "explicilit naming" in Oracle (I didn't find that in google), would you provide more information on what you trying to accomplish? Because if you're just running the query you don't need "as rows" at all.